# Salesforce Marketing Cloud : Journey History API

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to get journey history using journeyhistory end points

```
https://{{TenantId}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyHistory/search?$page=10&$pageSize=1000&$orderBy=TransactionTime%20desc
```

The problem i have,

1. I don't know how many records exist. The response message does not contact the "MoreDataAvailable" sort of indicator, so i don't from the response of first request , if more data is pending

[image]

how can i be sure if i get all data

1. response message always has contact key as

   ```
   "contactKey": "Contact Unknown",
   ```

   Thus i dont know what i am doing wrong. This value is for all 10000 record. i can expect this values if contact is deleted but not for all

I was expecting some sort of indicator which tell me if more data is available or not. Also value for contact key

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with "contactKey": "Contact Unknown",

I think when we use the API /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyHistory for the first time, something is not ready.

After a few hours, I did exactly that again and ContactKey starts populating

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).